# 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

```
Schema::create('students', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->integer('age')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('city_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('city_id')->references('id')->on('cities')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
});
Schema::create('cities', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->text('name');
        $table->timestamps();
});
```

i'm new laravel, when i run migrate, in terminal show

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `students` add constraint `students_city_id_foreign` foreign key (`city_id`) references `cities` (`id`) on delete cascade)

help me fix

Comment: Cities needs to be created before students, so if these are in the same file, switch the schemas around

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is on the order of the code. You want to make a foreign key to a table which is not yet exists.

Try this instead:

```
Schema::create('students', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->integer('age')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('city_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('cities', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->text('name');
        $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::table('students', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign('city_id')->references('id')->on('cities')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

Like this, you first creates both tables, and after that you set the foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using more recent version of Laravel `id` fields are now `unsignedBigInteger` field. So you should do something like:

```php
Schema::create('cities', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->text('name');
        $table->timestamps();
});
Schema::create('students', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->integer('age')->unsigned();
        $table->foreignId('city_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
});
```

Also, make sure the cities migration is running before students.

Comment: Why? what is the foreign table referencing to if he removes the `city_id` table??

Comment: Crap, you are right. I've gotten so used to defining it as `foreignId` and had quite forgotten we had to do it this way in earlier versions. Thanks for pointing that out. :)

Comment: Lol, you've got a point there mate

Answer (score 0):

```
=>your cities migration first create then after students migration create because your city_id foreign key reference to the cities table laravel migration check order and order wise migration run so first cities migration run(cities table create) then students migration run.
```